# Velocity: Is it possible to nest macros that use #@ and $bodyContent?

Tags: scope, velocity

I have a macro that looks essentially like this:

```
#macro( surround $x )
  surround:$x
    $bodyContent
  /surround:$x
#end
```

Invocation `#@surround("A")bunch o' stuff#end` produces "surround:A bunch o' stuff /surround:A" as
expected. Invocation `#@surround("A")#@surround("B")more stuff#end#end` produces
surround:A surround:B more stuff /surround:B /surround:A which is exactly what I want.

But now I want to build upwards with another macro

```
#macro( annotated-surround $x $y )
  #@surround( $x )
    annotate:$y
    $bodyContent
  #end
#end
```

The intended expansion of `#annotated-surround( "C" "note" ) stuff #end` is
    surround:C annotate:note stuff /surround:C

...but this doesn't work; I get the dreaded semi-infinite expansion of the annotated-surround body
content.

I have read the answer at [Closure in Velocity template macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12519289/closure-in-velocity-template-macros) and still don't quite know whether what I want to do is possible.

I'm willing to do arbitrarily tricky things within the definitions of `#surround` and
`#annotated-surround`, but I don't want the users of those macros to see any complexity. The
whole idea is to simplify their lives.

As long as I have your ear: Setting `macro.provide.scope.control=true` is supposed to "a local namespace in macros". What does this mean? Is the provided namespace independent of the default context, but with a single such space shared among all invocations of all macros? Or is a separate context provided for each macro invocation, even recursively? It has to be the latter because of `$macro.parent`, right?

And yet another question. Consider the following macro:

```
#macro( recursive $x )
  #if($x == 0)
    zero
  #else
    $x before . . . 
    #set($xMinusOne = $x - 1)
    #recursive($xMinusOne)
    . . . $x after
  #end
#end
```

`#recursive( 4 )` yields:

4 before . . .
3 before . . .
2 before . . .
1 before . . .
zero . . .
0 after . . .
0 after . . .
0 after . . .
4 after

Now I understand all those occurrences of "0": there's only one global $x, so assigning to it on
the recursive calls smashes it and it doesn't get restored. But where on earth does that final "4"
come from? For that matter, how is it that my first "surround" macro works to arbitrary depth;
how come its final $x doesn't get smashed in inner calls?

Sorry to be so prolix, but I have been unable to find clear documentation in this matter.

Comment: Three questions in one?  C'mon.  It's not that hard to open three separate questions.

Comment: But it's all the same question, namely, how to control scoping in velocity. Note how the first macro is also an example of the third question. And the "provide.scope" variables are undoubtedly going to figure in any answer. Let me assure you that I didn't combine these into one question because of the difficulty of opening two others.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the combination of global variables, a name collision, and lazy rendering.

Let's walk through the rendering process for `#@annotated-surround( "x" "y" )content#end`:

1. Rendering enters the `annotated-surround` macro. The context map contains:

   1. `$x` = String `x`
   2. `$y` = String `y`
   3. `$bodyContent` = Renderable `content` - note that the String output of this has not yet been evaluated.
2. Rendering of the first line enters the `surround` macro. This updates the context map to:

   1. new `$x` = old `$x` = String `x`
   2. `$y` = String `y`
   3. `$bodyContent` = Renderable `annotate:$y\n$bodyContent` - note that the String output of this still has not yet been evaluated, it's still template code.
3. Rendering outputs the first line of `surround`, producing the String `surround:x`.
4. Rendering begins evaluating the second line of `surround`, which references `$bodyContent`.

   1. Rendering the first line of `$bodyContent` produces the String `annotate:y`.
   2. Rendering begins evaluating the second line of `$bodyContent`, which references `$bodyContent`.

      1. Rendering the first line of `$bodyContent` produces the String `annotate:y`.
      2. Rendering begins evaluating the second line of `$bodyContent`, which references `$bodyContent`.

         1. etc.

The solution is to remove part of the problem's combination. Global variables and lazy rendering are fundamental parts of how Velocity works, so you can't touch those. That leaves the name collision. What you need is for each macro's `$bodyContent` to be referred to with a different name. This is easily achieved by assigning it to new variables with unique names in each macro before invoking any other macros, and using the new variable in any invoked macro's body, like this:

```
#macro( surround $x )
  surround:$x
    $bodyContent
  /surround:$x
#end

#macro( annotated-surround $x $y )
  #set( $annotated-surround-content = $bodyContent )
  #@surround( $x )
    annotate:$y
    $annotated-surround-content
  #end
#end
```

Rendering of this version goes like this:

1. Rendering enters the `annotated-surround` macro. The context map contains:

   1. `$x` = String `x`
   2. `$y` = String `y`
   3. `$bodyContent` = Renderable `content` - note that the String output of this has not yet been evaluated.
2. Rendering of the first line executes the `#set` directive, adding a variable to the context map: `$annotated-surround-content` = current `$bodyContent` = Renderable `content`.
3. Rendering of the second line enters the `surround` macro. This updates the context map to:

   1. new `$x` = old `$x` = String `x`
   2. `$y` = String `y`
   3. `$annotated-surround-content` = old `$bodyContent` = Renderable `content`
   4. `$bodyContent` = Renderable `annotate:$y\n$annotated-surround-content`
4. Rendering outputs the first line of `surround`, producing the String `surround:x`.
5. Rendering begins evaluating the second line of `surround`, which references `$bodyContent`.

   1. Rendering the first line of `$bodyContent` produces the String `annotate:y`.
   2. Rendering begins evaluating the second line of `$bodyContent`, which references `$annotated-surround-content`.

      1. Rendering `$annotated-surround-content` produces the String `content`.
6. Rendering outputs the third line of `surround`, producing the String `/surround:x`.

The final rendered output is `surround:x annotate:y content /surround:x`. This approach can be generalized by applying such substitutions to all occurrences of `$bodyContent` that are inside the content of another macro call, each time using a variable name derived from the macro's name to ensure uniqueness. It won't work for recursive macros without something extra to distinguish each nested invocation, however.

Regarding the scope setting, all that does is add a `$macro` object to the context, which is unique to each macro invocation and can be used as a map. If you set `$macro.myVar` to something different in each of two nested macro calls, the outer macro's value for it will be unchanged when the inner one finishes. This does not help with the `$bodyContent` issue, however, because any reference to `$macro` inside a macro's `$bodyContent` will be resolved to the innermost macro when it's rendered.

Regarding the final 4 from `#recursive( 4 )`, that comes from a combination of macro arguments having local scope and being passed by name. For all but the outermost invocation of `#recursive`, the argument `$x` is a reference to the global context variable `$xMinusOne` - when they render the `after` line, the use of `$x` is actually resolved to looking up the current value of `$xMinusOne` in the global context. For the outermost invocation it is instead the constant value `4`, and the arguments of the inner invocations go out of scope when they finish, so when the outermost one gets to the final line it's back to being `4`.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with the easiest, macro.provide.scope.control=true will definitely create a separate $macro scope object for *every* macro invocation.  Otherwise, as you note, the $macro.parent would be nonsense.  The whole point of the "scope controls" is to provide an explicit namespace for the type of VTL block in question.  You can even do surround.provide.scope.control=true to automatically create a $surround scope inside of #@surround bodyContent.

On your first question, i'm a little confused as to what's happening. Both the call to #@annotate-surround and the nested call to #@surround will make $bodyContent references available. Am i right that's what happening is that the "wrong" $bodyContent is being used?  The $bodyContent reference should belong to the nearest block macro call. To reference the outer macro's $bodyContent within the inner macro, you'll probably need to #set( $macro.bodyContent = $bodyContent ) and then, within the inner, use it via $macro.parent.bodyContent

As for #recursive weirdness, i don't know offhand and have to get on to other work now.  It also doesn't help that i don't have Velocity checked out on my present machine, so i can't quickly try things out.

Comment: You're right about the wrong bodyContent being used.

Your solution can fail if the outer bodyContent is nontrivial or if expansion order is important, eg #@annotate-surround("C" "note")#parse("foo")#end. Worse, #surround must know that it's being
called from a macro that stores bodyContent in this way. I want macros that are callable separately, nestable, and to be able to build more complex macros on top of them with their own bodyContent. I'm coming to the conclusion that there's no way to do this because even with per-macro contexts there's no way to keep bodyContent from being smashed.

Comment: Why can't you keep bodyContent from being smashed with #set( $macro.bodyContent = $bodyContent ) ??  Also, #setting the reference in that manner should not cause any problem with nontrivial bodyContent or premature expansion.  It's just a Block reference, it is not rendered by #set.

Comment: In any case, you're right, it would still require the inner macro to know it's being called in that way.  The best solution would probably be to change Velocity to automatically set $macro.bodyContent (when $macro is enabled), so that you can use that in macros and know it will never be smashed by an outer's bodyContent (as that would necessarily become $macro.parent.bodyContent.   Feel free to open a JIRA issue about this.  If you don't i probably will later.

Comment: I tried the suggestion and ran into a snag that seems to vitiate it. It's true that within the inner macro I want the outer macro's $bodyContent. But I need it at a specific point in the expansion, namely, at the point where the inner macro's $bodyContent says "$bodyContent". There's no place in the inner macro where it's correct just to say $macro.parent.bodyContent; you lose whatever else is in the inner $bodyContent (in the example, the material you lose is "annotate:$y"). If I've misunderstood the suggestion I'd greatly like to know where I went wrong. (Further comment coming.)

Comment: I found something a bit better. To write one $bodyContent-using macro that calls another, do this: #macro(outer) #set($macro.bC = $bodyContent) #@inner()..stuff...$macro.parent.bC ...stuff... #end #end  This works correctly and only the calling macro needs special care; #inner is untouched and can be used independently. But it's not general; #inner must use $bodyContent explicitly, not call a deeper inner macro. A macro built on #outer must say $macro.parent.parent.bC! In general, each macro must know how deeply its invoked macros pass $bodyContent. This isn't terrible, but can it be improved?

Comment: It's getting confusing, but i think you've got it.  As for improving your solution, i'm out of ideas that don't involve patching Velocity, which i have no time for in my current situation.